# SQL Developer 4 Toolbar

Tags: sql, sqldeveloper

Recently my SQL Developer toolbar became messed up.

I'm not sure what I did, and I can't change it back. When I got to `View-->Show toolbars-->Customize` Main Toolbar, it just says "initializing" and never says anything else.

Is something corrupt? Is there a fix? I am looking for buttons like: New worksheet; Open; Save, etc.

Comment: My toolbar is messed up, the "engineer" disappeared. I'm breaking into tears...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was very annoying.

I tried this and it worked for me:

1. Disable all toolbars.
2. Close & Open again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Customize just said "Initializing".
I had Version 4.1.1.19.
I went to Help-> Check for Updates and updated Oracle SQL Developer 
AND added Oracle Extensions and Third Party SQL Developer Extensions.
(I don't know whether adding the extensions was necessary, but I figured they might need to modify the toolbar, so they might fix whatever was broken.)
Anyway, it worked.

My ability to customize my menu came back, including my ability to reset my toolbar.